# wicke 6 AjaxLink within a Form

Tags: ajax, wicket

In an application written in Wicket 6, I (as a Wicket newbie) am trying to use an AjaxLink from within a form in order to be able to update the contents of the form.

My use case is the following : through ajax i want to be able to add/remove dynamically controls (file upload controls) to the form.

When using AjaxLink, I am not able to make an ajax call in order to add a new upload file control to the form. On the other hand, when I use AjaxFallbackLink the request gets submitted to the server and a new control is submitted. The only downside in this case is that the values previously selected on the form (the country from country dropdown) are lost.

Can someone explain me how can I cleanly add/remove controls to the form, with ajax, without affecting the other values selected on the form?

Bellow is a simplified version of the form class :

```
private final class MyForm extends BaseForm<MyFormBean> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9021809835323626044L;

    private List<Image> sfImages = new ArrayList<>();

    private MyForm(final String id, Sample sample) {
        super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel<>(new MyFormBean(sample)));
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        setMarkupId(id);

        setMultiPart(true);

        addWithFeedbackContainerAndLabel(new CountryDropDownChoice("country").setRequired(true));

        final WebMarkupContainer ajaxContainer = new AjaxUpdatableContainer("ajaxContainer");
        add(ajaxContainer);

        ajaxContainer.add(new ListView<Image>("sfImages", sfImages) {
            @Override
            public void populateItem(final ListItem<Image> listItem) {
                listItem.add(new UploadImagePanel("sfImage"));
            }
        });

        add(new AjaxLink("addSFImage")
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 974013580329804810L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                System.out.println("Ajax magic");

                MyForm.this.sfImages.add(new DynamicImage("53a4c88f78306456988af612"));

                if (target != null) {
                    target.add(ajaxContainer);
                }
            }
        });
        Button button = new SaveButton("saveButton");
        add(button);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I am not able to make an ajax call'? Do you have Javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: Does your AjaxUpdatableContainer set markup id to true? If not, use ajaxContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true); If you forget it, you would see an error in Wicket AJAX DEBUG BAR. I recommend to use it.

Comment: Question is not actually valid. While debugging the problem I've noticed in the browser console that there was a javascript error, reason why AJAX calls were not possible (AjaxFallbackLink was always making fallback calls). Thanks for the feedback